# VBA formulas fildown EXCEL report

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working an excel report. I've gotten some help on this site with editing my code but I'm stuck in one place and have no idea how to proceed. So I have code here:

```
Dim xlStartCol As Long
xlStartCol = xlCol
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
    .Resize(1, 2).Merge
    .Value = "TEST" 'g_RS3("ShortLabel")
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Clients", "Students")
    .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
    With .Offset(0, 1)
        .Resize(1, 2).Merge
        .Value = "Total"   'keep writing Total to the right; it will be overwritten if there is another ShortLabel
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Clients", "Students")
        .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).Formula = _
            "=SUMIFS(" & Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlCol + 1)).Address(0, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                         Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol + 1)).Address(1, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                         .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol - 1).Address(1, 0) & Chr(41)
    End With
    With .Resize(2, 4)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With
xlCol = xlCol + 2
g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop
```

This makes my report looks like this. What I'm trying to do is use fillDown property to autofill range [the formula is in 2 place under TOTAL, one under clients and one under students. sumifs: clients goes from cell to cell and grabs the number of clients for each TEST heading, same with Students](this row - where the formula is) : and + 6 rows down. Basically I want to have the formula in all 7 rows. Please help me out. Seem image below of what this code does.

[image]

Comment: So you are using @Jeeped answer from your last question but not marking his answer as correct?

Comment: I just marked it as completed. I'm new to this site and not exactly sure how everythign works. Thanks

Comment: Have you recorded yourself doing this?

Comment: No I actually got some help on this site.

Comment: Hove you looked into the [Range.Autofill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Yes I have. I have a good idea of how to do it, the problem i have is specifying the range. Because TOTAL gets written to the right everytime, and then overwritten if there is data in g_RS3 - I'm not sure how to specify what range to use for teh fill down. It has to be dynamic. The data in g_RS3 might change (more items might be added so I have to specify the correct range in this case)

Comment: How about just sticking (something like) this statement after you make your formula `.Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).AutoFill .offset(2,0).Resize(7,2)`

Comment: Thank you, please post as answer and ill mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just sticking this statement after you make your formula

```
.Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).AutoFill .offset(2,0).Resize(7,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this

```
Range("J4:J10").Formula = "=yourformulahere"
```